# d3.js zoom/drag scatter plot

Tags: plot, d3.js, zooming, behavior, scatter

I'm working on a d3.js scatter plot and I want it to be zoomable without resizing the dots. I've based it on http://static.cybercommons.org/js/d3/examples/zoom-pan/zoom-pan.html which has working zoomable grid lines, but so far I'm having trouble getting the points to zoom as well. When I zoom/pan, each point returns the following console alert:

> Unexpected value translate(NaN,0) parsing transform attribute.

You can see the full thing here, with screenshots of the design below it (click 'Open in a new window' to see the whole thing):
http://bl.ocks.org/242dcfc83d98743d8589

Simplified version of the JS here:

```
d3.csv("js/AllOccupations.csv", function(data) {

    var margin = {top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 50, left: 60},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var xMax = d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.TotalEmployed2011; }),
        xMin = 0,
        yMax = d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.MedianSalary2011; }),
        yMin = 0;

    //Define scales
    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([xMin, xMax])
        .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([yMin, yMax])
        .range([height, 0]);

    var colourScale = function(val){
        var colours = ['#9d3d38','#c5653a','#f9b743','#9bd6d7'];
        if (val > 30) {
            return colours[0];
        } else if (val > 10) {
            return colours[1];
        } else if (val > 0) {
            return colours[2];
        } else {
            return colours[3];
        }
    };


    //Define X axis
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .tickSize(-height)
        .tickFormat(d3.format("s"));

    //Define Y axis
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(5)
        .tickSize(-width)
        .tickFormat(d3.format("s"));

    var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom().x(x).y(y).scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoom));

    svg.append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

    // Create points
    svg.selectAll("polygon")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("polygon")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
            return "translate("+x(d.TotalEmployed2011)+","+y(d.MedianSalary2011)+")";
        })
        .attr('points','4.569,2.637 0,5.276 -4.569,2.637 -4.569,-2.637 0,-5.276 4.569,-2.637')
        .attr("opacity","0.8")
        .attr("fill",function(d) {
            return colourScale(d.ProjectedGrowth2020);
        });

    // Create X Axis label
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("class", "x label")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("x", width)
        .attr("y", height + margin.bottom - 10)
        .text("Total Employment in 2011");

    // Create Y Axis label
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("class", "y label")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("y", -margin.left)
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("dy", ".75em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .text("Median Annual Salary in 2011 ($)");


    function zoom() {
      svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
      svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
    }
});
```

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The grid lines in the example are, in fact, the axis ticks! So you will note that your zoom function updates them on mouse events, but you never update the dot positions. You should copy the point positioning lines into the zoom function (or break it out into a separate function).

This is what mine looks like:

```
function zoom() {
    svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
    svg.selectAll("polygon")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
            return "translate("+x(d.TotalEmployed2011)+","+y(d.MedianSalary2011)+")";
        })
        .attr('points','4.569,2.637 0,5.276 -4.569,2.637 -4.569,-2.637 0,-5.276 4.569,-2.637');
}
```

You can try it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/superboggly/2hfx3/)

Comment: Perfect! I figured that I needed to add something to the zoom function but I couldn't think what. Thank you so much!

For future reference: The solution you proposed lets the dots overflow the grid and onto the axes, so I wrapped them in an SVG to contain them as follows:


  svg.append("svg")
   .attr("class", "points")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height)
   .selectAll("polygon")
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append("polygon")
   ...